# A problem on Catalan numbers

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, catalan-numbers

Suppose two candidates A and B poll the same number of votes, $n$ each,
in an election. The counting of votes is usually done in some arbitrary order and
therefore, during the counting process A may lead for some period and B may lead for
some period. Prove that the number of ways of counting the votes such that A never trails B is
the $n^{th}$ catalan number.

I know that in such questions we are supposed to analyse the problem by dropping a few terms. For example, in this one, we can drop the $2n^{th}$ vote and check it for $2n-1$ votes, but it doesn't seem to be correct since I won't get catalan number. Can someone please help in getting a combinatorial argument/proof for this? Thanks!

Comment: Read sections 1.3 and 2.4 of http://www.geometer.org/mathcircles/catalan.pdf

Comment: Ya it's nice and thanks a lot for it. But, i was looking for more of a combinatorial proof

Comment: Consider each vote for $A$ as an opening parenthesis, and each vote for $B$ as a closing parenthesis. What are you counting now?